# Is there any way to 'auto hide' the navigation bar in Chrome mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-chrome

Please be nice, I scoured the forum on here looking for an answer to this and even got my already pitiful rating downgraded for asking this in the wrong place :(

I'm looking to make my site behave more like it does in the Firefox mobile browser by 'auto hiding' the URL/Nav bar after a second or so (to reappear when scrolling). Is there any known way of achieving this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Terry

Comment: Thanks @Luis P.A - I don't know how I missed that - looking into it NOW :)

Comment: Very, very helpful @LuisP.A. thanks so much! :)